# Working on react app and keep on getting the error Expected `onChange` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type

Tags: reactjs

To me it looks like a function is being passed and I am completely lost as for what to do to fix this error. I know passing this code directly to onChanged works, but for some reason when the onSearchChange method is passed as a parameter to the Searchbox it thinks it is an object

Here is the code in question

```
import "./tachyons";
import Searchbox from "./Searchbox";
import CardList from "./CardList";
import {robots} from "./robots";


class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            robots:robots,
            searchfield:""
        }
    }
    onSearchChange = (event)=>{
        //console.log(event);
        const filteredRobots = this.state.robots.filter(robots=>{
            return robots.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase());
        });
        console.log(filteredRobots);
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div className='tc'>
                <h1 className='f1'>RoboFriends</h1>
                <Searchbox searchChange = {this.onSearchChange}/>
                <CardList robots={this.state.robots}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

```
import App from "./App"
const Searchbox  = (searchfield, searchChange)=>{
  return (
    <div className="pa2">
      <input
        className = "pa3 ba b--green bg-lightest-blue"
        type="search"
        placeholder="search robots"
        onChange = {searchChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
export default Searchbox;
```

Comment: The props object is the first argument to your functional component. You can destructure the props object `({searchfield, onSearchChange})=>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Searchbox component isn’t destructuring the props:

```
const Searchbox = (searchfield, onSearchChange)=>
```

vs.

```
const Searchbox = ({searchfield, onSearchChange})=>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using props wrong way in `Searchbox` component. You need to update like this:

```
const Searchbox  = ({searchfield, onSearchChange})=>{...}
```